# how to read Charset UTF-8 encoded buffer in server java.nio

Tags: java, character-encoding, nio, decoding, utf8-decode

In the server my message is encoded

```
         `Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
          CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
          CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();
          readBuffer=encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(SAY_HELLO));
          readBuffer.flip();
          channel.write(readBuffer);`
```

and write to the channel but at server I cannot read the data am trying to read like

```
          `int count = channel.read(buffer);
         CharBuffer cbuf = decoder.decode(buffer);
         String s1 = cbuf.toString();`
```

Does anybody know how to read this encoded data in server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THERE WERE SOME PROBLEM IN THIS LINE `readBuffer=encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(SAY_HELLO));`
 I CAN SENT DATA WHEN I CHANGED TO `readBuffer.PUT(encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(SAY_HELLO)));`